# get wrapping element using preg_match php

Tags: php, preg-match

I want a preg_match code that will detect a given string and get its wrapping element.
I have a string and a html code like:

```
$string = "My text";
$html = "<div><p class='text'>My text</p><span>My text</span></div>";
```

So i need to create a function that will return the element wrapping the string like:

```
$element = get_wrapper($string, $html);

function get_wrapper($str, $code){
    //code here that has preg_match and return the wrapper element
}
```

The returned value will be array since it has 2 possible returning values which are `<p class='text'></p>` and `<span></span>`

Anyone can give me a regex pattern on how to get the HTML element that wraps the given string?

Thanks! Answers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: [using `preg_match` to parse HTML is bad bad bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Try http://php.net.dom and http://php.net/domxpath. if anyone suggests using a regex, beat them with a dead fish, and then go look at those two links.

Comment: @diEcho: can you give me a regex pattern that detects the given string ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's bad idea use regex for this task. You can use DOMDocument

```
$oDom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$oDom->loadXML("<div>" . $sHtml ."</div>");
get_wrapper($s, $oDom);
```

after recursively do

```
function get_wrapper($s, $oDom) {
    foreach ($oDom->childNodes AS $oItem) {
        if($oItem->nodeValue == $s) {
            //needed tag - $oItem->nodeName
        }
        else {
            get_wrapper($s, $oItem);    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple pattern would be the following, but it assumes **a lot of things**. Regexes shouldn't be used with these. You should look at something like the **[Simple HTML DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)** which is more intelligent.

Anyway, the regex that would match the wrapper tags and surrounding html elements is as follows.

> ```
>  /[A-Za-z'= <]*>My text<[A-Za-z\/>]*/g
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Even if regex is **never** the correct answer in the domain of dom parsing, I came out with another (quite simple) solution

```
<[^>/]+?>My String</.+?>
```

if the html is good (ie it has closing tags, < is replaced with < & so on). This way you have in the first regex group the opening tag and in the second the closing one.